# Static IPv4 & IPv6 configuration on openwrt linux

Tags: openwrt, ipv6, network-interface

The `/etc/config/network` file has the ipv6 and ipv4 entry for an eth0 interface. Executing `ifconfig eth0` shows both ipv4 and ipv6 address of that interface as per configuration.

Performing `ifconfig eth0 down` then `ifconfig eth0 up`, causes there is no ipv6 address on ifconfig eth0 output.

Why this IPv6 related specific behavior?